# How can I re-throw an exception in a lambda block as from the outer block?

Tags: java, exception, lambda, java-8

With following code,

```java
void key(Key) throws SomeCheckedException {
}

void supplier(Supplier<Key> s) throws SomeCheckedException {
    ofNullable(s).ifPresent(s -> {                   //    |
        try {                                        //    |
            key(s.get());                            //    |
        } catch (final SomeCheckedException sce) {   //    |
            // sce is coming from key() method       //    |
            // How can I throw sce for outer method? //  --/
        }
    });
}
```

How can I throw `sce` as if the method(`supplier`) method is throwing it?

Please note that above code is just an example. I need the `key(s.get())` to be inside a lambda expression.

```java
void supplier(Supplier<Key> s) throws SomeCheckException {
    key(s.get());
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn’t think of that `key(…)` may throw the checked exception. However [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27900544/2711488) handles that case as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to process checked exceptions in a safe manner you need a helper method which provides the facility of wrapping the exception into a sub-type of `RuntimeException`. Here is such a helper function which uses Generic’s type safety to ensure that only declared exceptions will be re-thrown (unless you use an unsafe operation):

```
public static <E extends Throwable> void attempt(
    Consumer<Function<E,RuntimeException>> action) throws E {

    final class CarryException extends RuntimeException {
        final E carried;
        CarryException(E cause) {
            super(cause);
            carried=cause;
        }
    }

    try { action.accept( CarryException::new ); }
    catch(CarryException ex) { throw ex.carried; }
}
```

It supports an arbitrary `action` which will receive a function which does the temporary wrapping of the checked exception type to the `RuntimeException`. This wrapping will be transparent, the method `attempt` will either complete normally or throw the original checked exception `E` (or an unrelated unchecked exception if one occurs).

So you can use it like this:

```
public static void processIterm(Supplier<Key> s)
    throws SomeCheckedException  {

    attempt( (Function<SomeCheckedException, RuntimeException> thrower) ->
        Optional.ofNullable(s).ifPresent(nonNull -> {
            try { key(nonNull.get()); } // assuming key may throw SomeCheckedException
            catch(SomeCheckedException  e) { throw thrower.apply(e); }
        }));
}
```

Due to the nested operations the compiler is unable to infer the exception type automatically. The code above use an explicit declaration of the `thrower` parameter type. Alternatively you can use a type invocation of the helper method like

```
ContainingClass.<SomeCheckedException>attempt( thrower ->
    Optional.ofNullable(s).ifPresent(nonNull -> {
        try { key(nonNull.get()); }
        catch(SomeCheckedException  e) { throw thrower.apply(e); }
    }));
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't. [`Supplier#get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html#get--) does not declare to throw any (checked) exceptions. Remember that a lambda expression simply creates an instance, it doesn't actually invoke the target functional interface method.

If you want to, you can wrap the checked exception in an unchecked exception and throw that.