# How throw the custom checked exception with java8 lambda expression?

Tags: java, java-8

I have the code below.

```
private static void readStreamWithjava8() {

    Stream<String> lines = null;

    try {
        lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("b.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        lines.forEachOrdered(line -> process(line));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (lines != null) {
            lines.close();
        }
    }
}

private static void process(String line) throws MyException {
    // Some process here throws the MyException
}
```

Here my `process(String line)` method throws the checked exception and I'm calling that method from within the lambda. At that point need to throw the `MyException` from  `readStreamWithjava8()` method without throwing `RuntimeException`.

How can I do this with java8?

Comment: Note: you can use try-with-resources with `Files.lines()`

Comment: @assylias Can you please share some sample code?

Comment: `try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(...))) { ... }` and remove the finally block.

Comment: @assylias Problem is my  process() method throws the Checked Exception  and how can I throw it from readStreamWithjava8() method.

Comment: @user3496599, try-with-resources is not about solving your problem. It's about writing shorter code.

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27896035/2711488) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18198176/2711488)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. This is because `forEachOrdered` takes a `Consumer`, and `Consumer.accept` is not declared to throw any exceptions.

The workaround is to do something like

```
List<MyException> caughtExceptions = new ArrayList<>();

lines.forEachOrdered(line -> {
    try {
        process(line);
    } catch (MyException e) {
        caughtExceptions.add(e);
    }
});

if (caughtExceptions.size() > 0) {
    throw caughtExceptions.get(0);
}
```

---

However, in these cases I typically handle the exception inside the `process` method, or do it the old-school way with for-loops.